# How do I host my React app on Github pages without getting redirected?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github

I have added a homepage, predeploy and deploy properties to my package.json file, linked my app to my github and ran npm run deploy. The terminal indicates success, then when I go to my Gitpages URL I get the following: https://joe-dp.github.io/mh-app/

Does anyone have any ideas why the link is redirecting me to a React information page?

Comment: Under Repo →  Settings →  Pages → Sources, you can select where your build app is. If you're app isn't yet built when you commit it, then you can create an action an action [like this one](https://github.com/Lissy93/email-comparison/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy-gh-pages.yml), which builds your app and places the built files in the `gh-pages` branch (which you should have selected the your GH pages source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Under Repo → Settings → Pages → Sources, and select the `gh-pages` branch
2. Put your built application (e.g. `dist`) at the root of the gh-pages branch to be served up

---

You'll probably want to automate this, which can be done quite easily with [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/actions).

The following example, uses [JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action](https://github.com/JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action), to build an deploy your app every time a change is made on your main branch.

Just create a file in `.github/workflows/deploy-gh-pages.yml` in your main branch, then populate it with:

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy to GH Pages
on: 
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions: 
  contents: write
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    concurrency: ci-${{ github.ref }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install and Build
        run: |
          yarn
          yarn build
      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4.3.3
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: dist
```

Commit your files, the action will run automatically, and a few minutes later your app will be live on GH Pages

If you'd like to see a real-world example of this, I'm doing something similar in [this project](https://github.com/lissy93/email-comparison).